# Why is Rails looking for SQLite3 on my production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, deployment

My `database.yml` looks something like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: mypwd
  host: /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

project is loaded on production server and i'm executing:

```
server:projectfolder admin$ rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production
```

and getting back:

```
Could not find sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.
```

I've done bundle install but not sure why it would even care about sqlite3 in prodution?!?

fyi - my Gemfile has:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Can anyone help me see what I've screwed up?

Comment: does seem odd, if you remove sqlite from the Gemfile altogether does it still do this? If so you may have a dependency with a Gemfile which references sqlite, are there any vendored gems?

Comment: OK, I comment out the sqlite3 lines in the Gemfile and then run my rake command again... and now it comes back saying it **Could not find webrat=0.7.2 in any of the sources.**  Webrat is listed in my Gemfile but only in a 'test' group?!?  what gives?  using **Rails 3.0.3** (or trying to)...

Comment: hmmm, i assume the app is mainly boilerplate generated? You haven't tweaked with anything internal? also was the actual original app generated with R3.0.3 or an earlier version?

Comment: by boilerplate i mean the app structure, not your code ;)

Comment: ya. it's truly boilerplate...well there are a few nonstandard gems (haml-rails, jquery-rails, rails3-generators, compass & simple_form) along with rspec & webrat in test. this app has only one model...  i'm just trying to get it deployed to test/prove I can round trip from local to server. apparently I'm failing...

Comment: does Rails 3 not respond to blocks like: `group :test do`?

Comment: @Meltemi - it does, but you have to tell `bundler` to ignore the `development` and `test` groups while installing on production. See my answer.

Comment: i'd remove all the groups, work systematically, and then see what happens, you might find they are masking a deeper exception. is this the only rake task that fails?

Comment: or see Fábio's answer :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug with bundler, but I'm getting a headache trying to trace through the code in definition.rb -- what I've figured out so far is that `specs` is calling `resolve.materialize(requested_dependencies)` which is triggering the error. This happens in the process of calling `specs.for` inside `specs_for(groups)`. I'd suggest filing a bug on github, as hopefully the committers understand this code better.

Comment: Could this be a user issue? I'm not that familiar with bundler in Rails 3 but does `bundle install` use sudo to install gems for all users or are they just being installed for the user that I issued the command as...so gems may not be accessible to the process/user that Rails will be running as when in production?

Comment: There's no bug, bundler will always try to create a full environment for you, with gems for production, development and test. If you want it to create an environment with just production gems, you'll have to instruct him to, using: `bundle install --without test development`. Check my answer.

Comment: @Fabio according to the bundler docs, you should be able to call `Bundle.require(:development)`, for example, but you can't make this call as `require 'bundler'` itself fails. That may just be how bundler is intended to work, that `require 'bundler'` fails if not all the gems specified are installed, unless it was installed with '--without', but to me this is a usability issue that's caused some confusion, so I would vote for fixing it (which would probably involve changing the validation logic from when the gem is required to when `Bundler.require` is called, so not sure if this will happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `sqlite3-ruby` gem is already into a group which does not include `:production`, you can just run:

```
env RAILS_ENV=production bundle install --without development test
```

This will create a `.bundle` directory, instructing ruby not to load any gem not set to `:production`.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, new to this, but should the gem be `'sqlite3-ruby'`?

Comment: Yes, it should... I just wrote it in a hurry.

Comment: ok. and what happens to the `:require => 'sqlite3'` portion in my original statement. is it no longer necessary?

Comment: You can keep it, I guess. Try and let's see how it goes.

Comment: ok. doing this it worked...but I don't know why?!? I still have sections in my Gemfile for `group :development do` *and* `group :test do` *and* `group :production do`. i only changed the one for `group :development, :test do` to what Fábio recommended above. and ran that `env` command... and now the schema has loaded! **Does anyone know why?** I don't understand enough yet to understand what this change actually did for me...but I'd love to know.

Comment: The bundle command you ran basically told Ruby to skip anything in groups `:development` and `:test`. This is valid for both the short syntax (that I recommended for sqlite3) and the block syntax (the ones you're using for webrat, etc). Both are interchangeable, so if you want you can keep your `gem` declaration like it was before. I just noticed you already had sqlite3 on a group block, so you didn't really needed to change the line to the one I told you, just running `bundle install --without test development` would work fine.

Comment: I updated my answer to make clear that the 1st change is not really needed. Just the `bundle install`.

Comment: Very helpful... now, I almost have everything working...except when I try to load the page in a web browser I get a similar error from Phusion Passenger: `Could not find sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`.  Now what!?! I suppose I could just remove all the environment restrictions but I'd really like to understand what's I'm doing wrong... so I don't do it again, hopefully ;-)   So why is Passenger looking for these gems now? Why should it care if it's in 'production'. Does it know it's in 'production'? Not sure how to tell...

Comment: That's weird, Bundler should be configured now to ignore the `sqlite3-ruby` gem. Have you restarted your Apache after running `bundle install`?

Comment: Can Passenger see your `.bundle` directory? Try performing an `chmod -R apache:apache .` while on your application directory.

Comment: hmmm. _I_ can't even see my `.bundle` directory. at least not at the root of my project... where is this directory?

Comment: what user is my server trying to run this Rails app as? how can i find out? maybe i need to change the `RAILS_ENV` variable in that user's `.bashrc` file?!?  I don't have an 'apache' user or group.

Comment: Crap! Now, when I try to hit the app in a browser I get this "We're sorry but something went wrong" image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?198293bf49.png  Man Rails is killing me today....

Comment: "we've been notified about it"? who is "we"??

Comment: "We" is you, this is the message that appears to your customers when they access your site and there's an error. Check `log/production.log`, or disable custom errors, by changing the line that says `config.consider_all_requests_local` on your `config/environments/production.rb` to `true`. Then restart your app by running `touch tmp/restart.txt`.

Comment: ok. production.log had the answer. didn't think to look there as app appeared to be running in development environment. had a problem with my database.yml setup. fixed now. thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
export RAILS_ENV='production'
rake ...
```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to what he ran?

Comment: but now echo `$RAILS_ENV` returns `production` instead of a blank line.

Comment: What environment is loaded if you run `rails c`? Are you in production?

Comment: `rails c` barfs back the same error: `Could not find sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2 in any of the sources`

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe this is a user problem? maybe i'm logging into the server as the wrong user? which user would the Rails app normally run under the same one as Apache? maybe i need to make sure i'm installing the gems, and running the rake tasks as *that* user?!?